# mt6537M Resize Partitions

Tags: partitions, system, flashtool

I've a rooted smartphone with lollipop 5.1 and chip mt6537M...

### Store:

- Emulated legacy (5.35 gb media + store) and 1gb for system rom (300 free T_T)

### Objective:

I would like change the size of partitions... Note: It haven't `EBR` Instead has `tee1` and `tee2`, but I don't know about tee partitions...

### Possible way and question:

I was thought maybe with **`cat`** or **`dd`** command could clone *mmbclk0* and resize in a pc or with internal tools from recovery mode (TWRP 3.0)

example:

```
 "cat /dev/block/mmcblk0 > /external_sd/allpartitions.cat"
```

Someone could guide me by the best way...? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean to clone with 'cat' command?  'cat' is used to display, merge files.. I think if you want to resize partitions you'll have to deal with kernel and maybe hard brick phone if you don't do it right.

Comment: clone with `cat /dev/block/mmcblk0 > /external_sd/allpartitions.cat`

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Can you guide me ? thank you dude

Comment: You won't manage to do anything with 'cat'. Sorry I can't guide you this is mostly guess, but accurate one I think. Ask on XDA maybe there is someone who can help you, or google it there must be some tutorial.

Comment: I don't understand you. Of course you need an accont to open thread there..

Comment: Yes but If i want publish a post, I must win points with answers xD @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје